# Using colspan in code-based datatable columns setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

it's the first question here, so forgive me any mistakes.

I'm using the JQuery Datatables plugin and have to add two rows of column headers with colspans to my table. Hardcoded in HTML there is no problem, but right now I need it at the initialization  of the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover small-table myTable"></table>    

$('.myTable').DataTable({
            bProcessing: true,
            bServerSide: true,
            paging: true,
            lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, 250, 500], [25, 50, 100, 250, 500]],
            pageLength: 100,
            order: [2],
            sAjaxSource: 'path/to/myAjaxController',
            sServerMethod: 'POST',
            columns: [
                { title: 'Col1', searchable: true, sortable: false },
                { title: 'Col2', searchable: true },
                { title: 'Col3', searchable: true, sortable: true },
                { title: 'Col4', searchable: true }
            ]
        });
```

So right now I need to add a "major-col" to "Col1" and "Col2" and another "major-col" to "Col3" and "Col4".

It should be looking like:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Major-Col1</th>
      <th colspan="2">Major-Col2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
      <th>Col4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Thank you for any suggestion. :)

Comment: It's working for you?? https://jsfiddle.net/jevtw2g4/13/

Comment: Not really, sorry. That the colspan is working while using it in HTML I already new. But right now I need it without using any HTML than the table-tag itself. But thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got a response of the developer-team:

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/94186#Comment_94186

So right now it is NOT possible to set the colspan without using HTML.